# Acl Manager Plugin for CakePhp

Tags: cakephp-2.0, acl

Please could anyone help! I'm using CakePhp plugin 'Acl Manager', and I'm having trouble while getting to the permissions link :

```
localhost/cake/acl_manager/acl/permissions
```

Error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 114149015 bytes) File: E:\wamp\www\cake\lib\Cake\View\View.php Line: 964

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from your question that you can't get into the admin pages of the Acl Plugin at all. Here is a solution to that issue.

The normal link to to Acl Manager looks like:

[http://<domain name goes here>/admin/acl](http://%3Cdomain%20name%20goes%20here%3E/admin/acl)

Or in your case:

http://localhost/admin/acl

Once you get to that page you should be able to navigate using the GUI to all the features you want to use.